# ERROR IN parameter passing in pivot table mysql

Tags: mysql

UPDATED:

I am using pivot table for displaying column names as header as per my knowledge everything is fine but when i tried to add parameter I am getting error while

calling

call sp_schreport(1,2,'2014-10-04'); $$

AND WHEN I TRIED TO ADD

```
"select venue,'null' as first,'null' as second,'null' as third,'null' as   fourth from sch_venue where campusid =campid and venueid NOT IN (select venueid from  sch_taskassigned where assignedstatus=status AND (sdate BETWEEN taskstartdate AND  taskenddate)) UNION"
```

along with that code getting error for union function both query column should be equal so that only i have used 'null' first etc..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_schreport(IN campid int,IN status int,IN sdate datetime)
 BEGIN
 SET @sql = NULL;

 SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'max(CASE WHEN t.session = ''',
  t.session,
  ''' THEN d.department END) AS `',
  tagname, '`'
)
) INTO @sql
FROM sch_sessions t;
 SET @sql 
= CONCAT('select venue,'null' as first,'null' as second,'null' as third,'null' as   fourth from sch_venue where campusid =campid and venueid NOT IN (select venueid from  sch_taskassigned where assignedstatus=status AND (sdate BETWEEN taskstartdate AND  taskenddate))
  UNION SELECT v.venueid, ', @sql, ' 
       from sch_taskassigned p
       left join sch_sessions t
           on p.sid = t.sid inner join sch_venue v on p.venueid=v.venueid inner join  sch_departments d where p.campusid=campid and p.assignedstatus=status and (sdate BETWEEN   taskstartdate AND taskenddate) group by p.venueid');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END$$
```

Kindly find out the mistakes in my procedure

Comment: what is error and what parameter you are trying to add?

Comment: mysql>  call sp_schreport(1,2,'2014-10-04'); $$
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'campid' in 'where clause'

Comment: campid is a field or parameter? if it is a field.. which table field is?

Comment: add alias name before campid  and try

Comment: Am i supposed to declare like this, DECLARE cid int; SET @campid=cid; then assign cid for my querry or straightly @campid for my query